# Capture outgoing ASP.NET traffic from windows 10 with Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I recently upgraded to windows 10, and have discovered an issue that I was able to do on Windows 8.1, but seem to be unable to do on Windows 10.

In my ASP.NET web application I have a controller that receives a GET request and then issues it's own GET request to another server and then sends that response back.

When debugging I have added the following to the application web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Which in 8.1 was able to capture both the local server request and the remote server request. However, I haven't been able to get Windows 10 to do the same.

I did exempt all in the WinConfig settings on Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

`WinConfig` won't affect anything; it only relates to Metro/Immersive apps.

If you update `web.config` to point to a bogus proxy (e.g. `127.0.0.1:1111`) does it fail? If not, then your app isn't using the configured proxy settings.

If updating `web.config` doesn't work, you might try editing the appropriate (probably 64bit) `machine.config`.